# AVD manager is empty and unable to create a new one

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, android-virtual-device

AVD manager is empty as well as unable to create a new one, the "Ok" button is disabled in the Create New Android Virtual Device (AVD) dialog.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

try to create a new AVD. Make sure while u create the AVD, dont enter any spaces in AVD name and select the device, also make sure system images get loaded. Ok button will get enabled if u fulfill all these conditions